# Android XML Views side by side

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been working with a layout that contains 3 textView and one imageView. All together it should form a square. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

and I am quite happy with the look. The problem is my code, as the views are set with android:layout_marginLeft/right and Top and i would like it to be set by maybe android:layout_toLeftOf and toRightOf if possible, and the make a margin between all the views on 5-10dp or so.

So please help me re-write my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background3"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#90000000"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="#90000000"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="#90000000"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="#E97305"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="#90000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="123dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
        android:paddingBottom="22dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:background="#90000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  may try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background3"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#90000000"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="#90000000"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/relativeLayout2"
        android:background="#90000000"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textColor="#E97305"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#90000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:paddingBottom="22dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/detail"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#90000000"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```